# how to ember.js redirect to another page?didn't use transitionToRoute

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I gotted 2 pages like A.jsp and B.jsp

generally we use Route like this:

```
  var A= this.get('controllers.A');
  A.("id",1);
  this.transitionToRoute('A');
```

but i want redirect to B.jsp And set B.id's value.

if at the A.jsp use transitionToRoute the path like:A.jsp#home not the B.jsp#home...

so how to do?

Comment: what do you mean by 'set B.id's value'?

Comment: Why do you talk about separate JSPs? This would mean 2 separate Ember Apps

Comment: i want send the id to ohter page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to redirect to A, and pass that value in, you can just do this

```
this.transitionToRoute('a', 1);
```

This creates a new A controller, so you have to pass the value in the transitionToRoute, because the A that you have a reference to inside of B will be out of scope once the transition happens. Or if you wanted it dynamic from the B controllers data.

```
this.transitionToRoute('a', this.get('content.id'));
```

Comment: if  i this.transitionToRoute('a', 1);
at the acontroller how to get the value of '1'?

Comment: Inside of your aRoute you would set the model in the setupController function.  Then inside aController you can access it with this.get('content.id')

Comment: i didn't use Ember.Model.how to get 'id' at Controller?